# How to get the last executed transaction?

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I work with a Wallet app and using the `BitcoinJ` for programming. I need to find the last executed transaction from the wallet. In the `org.bitcoinj.core.Wallet` class, I see there is a method `getTransactionsByTime()` that returns list of all non-dead, active transactions ordered by recency as `List<Transaction>`.

Will I access the most recent transaction with index 0 or the last index? I have made some experiments and I likely think that would be with `index of 0`. Because, it returns the sending info and I have done some recently, but, still weird as the amount doesn't match with performed.

While I have tried with the last index, I think that's obviously not the case as that's returns the info of the incoming transactions.

The way I find the most recent transaction,

```
    transactions.addAll(wallet.getTransactionsByTime());    
    Transaction ts = size > 0 ? getTransactions().get(0) : null;
    this.transaction = addTransactionHistory(ts);
```

I print the `transaction` as the most recent one in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first transaction in the list should be the newest one.

The best way to answer such questions is always to read the source code. [`getTransactionsByTime`](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/943a139d0846afb4f1432a1cfcd3949f52dede28/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/wallet/Wallet.java#L2918) calls [`getRecentTransactions`](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/943a139d0846afb4f1432a1cfcd3949f52dede28/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/wallet/Wallet.java#L2930), and there is a [comment](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/943a139d0846afb4f1432a1cfcd3949f52dede28/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/wallet/Wallet.java#L2923):

> Returns an list of N transactions, ordered by increasing age.

You can trace down to find [the critical minus sign](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/c24ef97ac036fcb3ec7b20597968c4a4984076b8/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/core/Transaction.java#L73) that ensures this.

You can also find [a test](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/6841fceabc380301a2a85d616aea491bf7ee3de5/core/src/test/java/org/bitcoinj/wallet/WalletTest.java#L1457) that explicitly verifies it works as documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I'm new to cryptocurrency and  developing a customized wallet.